# Using JOIN in NotORM

Tags: php, sql, notorm

Been trying the following code

```
$notorm->table()->select("table.*, table2.column, table2.table3.column2");
```

from http://sql-cross-queries.freexit.eu/dibi/notorm to create a JOIN statement, but to no avail. Am I missing out on anything?

I have reports(timestamp, incident_id, location id), incident(incident_id, incident_desc, location_id), and location(location_id, location_name). I am trying to get timestamp, incident_name, and location_name by joining reports, incident, and location. So I used the following statement:

```
$notorm->reports()->select("reports.*, incident.incident_id, incident.location.location_id");
```

but it's not returning anything. The following statement, though:

```
$notorm->reports()->select("reports.*");
```

returns reports.

Comment: Please describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not 100% sure but worth a try.

```
$notorm->reports()->join("reports", "LEFT JOIN incident ON reports.incident_id = incident.incident_id")
->join("reports", "LEFT JOIN location ON reports.location_id = location.location_id")
->select("reports.timestamp, incident.incident_desc, location.location_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `table` definition, there must be a field name `table2_id` present